# Dez anos de Stack Overflow em Português!

Tags: debate

O Stack Overflow em Português irá completar dez anos em *11 de Dezembro*!

Vamos pensar um pouco sobre algumas das coisas legais sobre este site, algumas lembranças divertidas que você possa se recordar, talvez algumas curiosidades divertidas do site ou qualquer outra coisa que vier à mente.

Agradecemos a todos que colaboraram com o conteúdo!

Comment: Parabéns!  Feliz Aniversário :)

Comment: Maravilhoso !!!

Answer (score 12):

A maior parte do que aprendi de 2015 até hoje veio do SOpt. Há 8 anos e 6 meses estava criando minha conta aqui e fazendo [minha primeira pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61003/como-criar-duas-classes-com-mesmos-m%c3%a9todos-mesmo-uma-delas-n%c3%a3o-sendo-partial). Na época o Windows Forms ainda era relevante então comecei na programação com Visual Basic .NET.

Eu vi várias pessoas daqui me acompanharem neste percurso. O aprimoramento profissional que tive nessa comunidade fortaleceu não só na programação mas como um indivíduo social e comecei a me sentir um voluntário.

Em 2019 eu foquei mais na comunidade e a relação entre perguntas x respostas eram bem balanceados, sinal que do que aprendia, também conseguia ajudar, era uma via de mão dupla. Foi assim com vb.net, C#, PHP, html/css e Javascript. Aprendi muita coisa bacana.

Além disso, as pessoas que conheci aqui valeram muito a pena de ter entrado na comunidade. Conheci pessoas que considero amigos, que me ensinaram a ser mais profissional e encarar o mercado da programação. Destes amigos, alguns me incentivaram à ser ativo na comunidade, colaborar com projetos de código aberto e testar seus grandes projetos.

Em suma, essa comunidade me ensinou a *conviver corretamente em uma sociedade de programadores*, e ainda acho que estou longe de saber tudo sobre isso. Temos bons moderadores, não são todos, mas são pessoas que ainda cuidam do site, mesmo quando parece estarmos abandonados por quem deveria ser nosso parceiro.

Answer (score 3):

Sou um dos entusiasmados que entraram no SOpt assim que viu a notícia no site principal e começaram a aparecer os icônicos banners escritos em português. Aprendi muita coisa de lá pra cá, sejam pelas perguntas ou pelas respostas. As perguntas eram mais flexíveis, desfavoráveis as regras da comunidade, mas era o que mantinha o site ativo e vibrante, com discussões e pautas a favores e contras e foi muito legal participar de tudo isso, inclusive aqui no meta.

No início era tudo muito "cru", lembro de brigar com meus amigos para ver quem respondia mais perguntas e quem postava perguntas mais relevantes no site, rsrs, isso se foi ao tempo em que hoje já não existem tantas perguntas para se fazer, já que muitas delas já foram feitas e respondidas.

Com as regras mais rígidas e consolidadas e a moderação mais "moderada", acabei abandonando o SOpt. Minha intenção de ajudar a galera daqui se foi ao ver várias perguntas tomando negativo em menos de 2 minutos, isso passava uma impressão ruim, não sei se ainda passa. Devo ser um dos poucos antigos e que não são mais ativos do site que tem coragem de vir aqui escrever uma resposta.

Ainda fico feliz em recordar essa época. Me sentia parte da comunidade e dos programadores. Era meu site número 1 para sanar minhas dúvidas e fazer perguntas de coisas que eram difíceis de encontrar por aí e a galera daqui era bem receptiva e respondia muita coisa.

Pena que muita coisa disso se perdeu com o tempo. Amava muito tudo isso. Hoje nem me sinto mais parte e é um pouco triste. Quem sabe ano que vem eu volte a participar mais ativamente por aqui. O que sobra é a nostalgia.

Ainda assim, muito obrigado a todos, vocês fizeram e fazem parte da minha história profissional e sou muito feliz por isso!

Um abraço!

Comment: Esperamos que volte a participar em breve. Tenha em mente que *quantidade **não** é qualidade*, melhor maior rigidez focando o conteúdo do site na qualidade, do que uma série de respostas em perguntas helpdesk , já que o objetivo do site não é *suporte técnico pessoal* e nem nunca foi. **Nota:** [modera](https://dicionario.priberam.org/modera): controlar, suster, atenuar, restringir, fazer diminuir ou diminuir a intensidade ou a quantidade de algo excessivo.

Comment: @Reptile, entendo o ponto de vista, mas não julguei a qualidade do conteúdo, até mencionei sobre as regras da comunidade, mas frisei somente a quantidade mesmo ;). Não sei se ficou claro, preferiria um lugar mais acolhedor com perguntas helpdesk do que um restrito que diminui a quantidade de usuários a cada dia e esse foi o motivo de abandonar o SOpt, por mais ruins que sejam eu aprendia algumas coisas com esses tipos de pergunta. Talvez seja eu que não me encaixei depois de tanta mudança e tá tudo bem.

Comment: Concordo com você. O SOpt me ajudou muito no início da carreira e sou muito grato. Infelizmente, me afastei da comunidade pelos mesmos motivos que vc. Talvez eu não fosse de ajudar tanto, quanto vc, devido a minha inexperiência. Mas eu participava da comunidade e gostava muito daqui. Infelizmente hoje, a meu ver, a comunidade morreu e vive de um belo passado e da sua grande base de dados deixada. As tão sonhadas reputações morreram com os seus donos (conosco) e hoje servem apenas de enfeite para seus respectivos totens. Seus tópicos ficam como resultados para buscas no google e similares. ♥

Answer (score 1):

Desses 10 anos, eu participei uns 70% a 80% desse tempo. Pra mim foi um salto enorme de aprendizado profissional e fiz bons amigos e parceiros profissionais com os quais tenho contato até hoje.

Fiz minha primeira pergunta há uns 9 anos atrás, vindo do Google, e obtive a resposta que eu buscava, graças a Deus. Depois de uns anos eu comecei a frequentar o site de forma mais assídua, para aprender e ensinar, mas eu muito mais aprendi do que ensinei... aliás, o que fui aprendendo fui passando pros que buscavam tais informações.

Parabéns SOpt pelos seus 10 anos!